# Error : IDTSDesigntimeComponent100.AcquireConnections HRESULT: 0xC020801C during SSIS pkg creation

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

USING:

- x64
- Windows server 2012
- SQL 2014 Enterprise Installation
- Visual Studio 2012
- SSDT for VS 2013

When I open a precreated package with same connection in SSDT for VS 2013 on same machine, I can open the connection and connect to the VFP source and I can preview the data.

However, building an SSIS package using the DTS components in VS 2012. This package has a FoxPro connection manager and with an OLDEDB datasource: DTSAdapter.OleDbSource.4

The Visual Fox Pro Driver needed does not come in x64 bit: VFPOLEDB.1

The errors I get:

```
IDTSComponentMetaData100 component = CreateComponent(pipeline, DataFlowConstant.ComponentID.OLEDBSource);
```

The errors:

```
CManagedComponentWrapper componentWrapper = component.Instantiate();
```

After running that line of code the object has this error in it, but it doesn't throw:
***Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))***

Then when this line is called:

```
 componentWrapper.AcquireConnections(null);
```

This error is thrown:
 **- Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020801C
 - DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER**

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

I am having this same exact issue

http://i.imgur.com/um3WIXj.png

Answer (score 0):

From what I've discovered, it appears to be related to the MSIL mismatch error that appears after referencing the DTS libraries.

Going to try switching the configurations to X86 to force 32-bit (which kinda sucks but doesn't really affect my app much) and see if that fixes my issue.